# Why is the extension of my ini files nothing?

Tags: file, delphi, load, ini

I have a procedure to save a file, which is an ini file. The procedure below is just where the user chooses the directory and name of the file:

```
procedure TForm1.SaveFile(Sender: TObject);
var
  Dialog : TSaveDialog;
begin
  Dialog := TSaveDialog.Create(self);
  try
    //dialog properties go here
    Dialog.Filter := 'Title (*.ini)|*.ini';
    Dialog.Options := Dialog.Options + [ofOverwritePrompt];
    if Dialog.Execute then
    begin
      //any saving procedures go here if required

      ShowMessage('File saved: ' + Dialog.FileName);
    end 
  else
      ShowMessage('Save file was cancelled');
  finally
    Dialog.Free;
  end;
end;
```

As you can see I set the filter to `ini` but no files show at all (it still saves)
The procedure below is where the user can select a previously saved file

```
procedure TForm1.LoadFileBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
Var
FileName, FileExtension : String;
SelectedFile : TOpenDialog;
begin
SelectedFile := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
Try
  if SelectedFile.Execute() then     
   FileName := SelectedFile.FileName        
   else
   //Do whatever here if user doesn't select file
Finally
  SelectedFile.Free;  //Free dialog from memory

End;
  FileExtension := ExtractFileExt(FileName);

  if not (FileExtension = 'ini') then
    exit
    else
//Do whatever here if file extension matches specified type
end;
```

I get the extension of the filename and check if its ini. The `ShowMessage` is there to see what value is returned for testing purposes. When i click an ini file nothing is returned but when i click a text file '.txt' is returned. Why do my ini files save with the type as 'File' when they are ini files.

How could i change my load file procedure to detect if its an ini file and if not then exit?

Comment: I suspect you are not saving your files as ini files. Do you have the DefaultExt property set to 'ini'? Have you checked with explorer that your files really do have the correct extension?

Comment: Why won't you debug your code? You keep asking questions here that could be answered if you would debug your code. Until you make an effort to learn how to debug you are doomed to be stuck forever asking questions like this.

Comment: There are  many more bugs. Debugging will reveal them. You haven't got time to learn how to debug. That is nonsense. You haven't got time not to.

Comment: @Not_Lucas:" I spend days searching hours searching google for how to fix a problem"  Well, a classic case of more haste, less speed: You could have learnt how to use the debugger in far less time (couple of hours at most) and then solved your problem here in a few minutes.

Comment: Indeed. If you think asking a question here is more productive than debugging you are sorely mistaken. Oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the property DefaultExt in the SaveDialog to '.ini'
These will solve your problem

Comment: Yes, that's the better way to do it, and slipped my mind.  +1

Answer (score 1):

I think you are assuming that the fact that you are specifying the SaveDialog's `Filter` as you do forces the SaveDialog's `FileName` to have an extension of 'Ini'.  It does not.  The dialog's `Filter` property determines what files are listed in it, not the extension that the saved file has.

Try the following code:

```
if SaveDialog.Execute then
begin
  SaveSeatingPlan(SaveDialog.FileName);
  Assert(SameText(ExtractFileExt(SaveDialog.FileName), '.Ini'));
  ShowMessage('File saved: ' + SaveDialog.FileName);
end else
  ShowMessage('Save file was cancelled');
```

Instead of the `Assert`, you can of course append the '.Ini' extension in your code or, better, do what the other answer suggests.

Comment: I've fixed it with the other solution you recommended but I assumed that it would save it as an INI file due to other code where I use code like ini.writeinteger or ini.writestring etc, not the filter.